# Instagram logout page / API not working

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Unlike the FaceBook API, Instagam does not provide an official logout API, so I implemented it by calling the logout URL (https://instagram.com/accounts/logout) using an iframe to log out the instagram in my app. 
However, I recently noticed that the Instagram logout did not work by changing the logout page invocation from HTTP Get to Post.:(

Many developers will be experiencing the same issue,
If you know someone who can solve the problem, Please let me know!!